# when loading libtensorflow_framework.so in python, error Internal: platform is already registered with name: "Host"

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

_python version: python 3.6
tensorflow version:tf 1.8.0, installed using the binary pip package on the website
cuda version: 9.0  cudnn version: 7.0
bazel version: 0.11.0

I compiled the tensorflow c++ library using the following command:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --local_resources=6144,4,1.0 --jobs=4 //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```

in the same folder as libtensorflow_cc.so, libtensorflow_framework.so is also generated.

I loaded `libtensorflow_framework.so` in python:

```
tf.load_op_library("/u/deng/bazel_outputRoot_old_ABI/_bazel_deng/26385c5408ff67f7a1c5af10169be67b/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so")
```

and got:

```
2018-07-10 14:52:31.793546: F 
tensorflow/stream_executor/host/host_platform.cc:97] 
Non-OK-status: gpu::MultiPlatformManager::RegisterPlatform(std::move(platform)) status: 
Internal: platform is already registered with name: "Host"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried using the tensorflow compiled from source, but the error remains the same.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That library that you are trying to load is already loaded, the python TF framework depends on it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I want to load a custom op in python, which depends on tensorflow c++ library, namely libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so compiled using the command I mentioned in the question, they are in the folder tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow. I know there is a libtensorflow_framework.so in python TF package, I think this is the one you mentioned, but if I load this one, there will be an "undefined symbol" error when loading tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so, because the symbol is defined in  tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so

Comment: tf so loaded twice would trigger this error, please make sure the so only load once.